# Is there a way to print message using makefile whenever any makefile command fails?

Tags: makefile

I was compiling a program using makefile and wanted to display a message to the user if there is any error in the program.
I searched for this and found that the exit status is zero if make is successful else it is non-zero.
How to use these values of exit status to accomplish the above task or is there any other way of doing so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a bash script and call make command in that, you can check result of each command(or which command you want to check if successful) and print a message using echo if it fails as

```
#!/bin/bash
cd <YOUR_DIRECTORY_CONTAINING_MAKEFILE>
make
if [ $? -ne "0" ]; then
 echo "Make failed"
 exit 1
fi
echo "make Successful"
```

$? holds result of last command.

Now, to make your program and see result, you have to run this bash script

Comment: This is not working. It is showing "makefile:6: *** missing separator.  Stop." where line 6 is the line containing exit 1

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake, just edited my answer, can you cehck now

Comment: Same can be expressed in on-liner bash script: `make $* || echo "make failed"`.

Comment: You should use `make "$@" || echo "make failed"` (`"$@"` not `$*`).

Comment: we are trying to get exit status of last command, So $? is fine